# New comment w/ajax - owner_id not in request parameters until page is refreshed

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a comments form which attaches to the "revision" of a "section". If no revision exists, an empty one is created. The add comment form is loaded with ajax. The issue, is that if several comments are added without refreshing the page, several empty revisions are created. This causes havoc in certain edge cases.

I request a new add comment form with ajax every time the add comment button is hit. However, Rails thinks there's no new information and serves 304 not modified. There is new information - the comment form on the second request should have a populated "owner_id" which is the id of the empty revision created by the first comment.

I'm positive the owner_id population works as refreshing the whole page fixes the issue. I used to think this was a server cache issue but looking at the parameters of the request, owner_id is missing until the page is refreshed.

**Update:** I added expire_now() to the new action on comments controller and it's now serving a 200 response but the contents still have no owner_id.

**Another update:** Looking in the console, the parameters of the request don't include the owner_id. Refreshing the page *then* requesting the form suddenly includes the owner_id in the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure about the details on this, but an ajax request is different from a page request in a number of ways. For example, controller code is not updated when just requesting a view with ajax. In my case, there is also difference of not having owner_id as a populated parameter for ajax views.

In the new action on the comments controller, I had to manually query the section to see if there was a revision, and if so, set the owner_id with the revision id.

```
def new
  # precaution against creating multiple empty revisions if user adds multiple comments without refreshing page
  if params[:owner_id].nil?
    revision = @section.send(params[:snip_type]).first
    unless revision.nil?
      @comment.owner_id = revision.id
    end
  end
end
```